# How to handle pop up windows in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, testautomationfx

I need to handle a pop up window on an eCommerce site using Robot Framework.
I'm unable to post screenshots of the actual site I am working on but It is similar situation to the following. I select the item I want to purchase [image: Item to purchase]
Then I click on the Buy it now Button and a mini window pops up as follows: [image]
The problem I am having is that Robot is not picking up the mini pop up window. I tried using the select window keyword, Set Focus to Element keyword but no luck as the elements within the mini window are not being found.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue with you today and below is the way that I did:

1. Using `Inspect Element` to know exactly which type of popup (ex: iframe,...)
2. Get exactly locator of this iframe
3. Using `Select Frame` keyword, then I can do everything with element on this popup

Below is my example:

```html
Click Button    id:btnAddNewProduct
Sleep   20s
Select Frame    xpath://div[@id='ContentModel']//iframe
Log to console  OK
```